# Proof checking : if $A$ and $B$ are finite sets then so $A \cap B$ finite

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, solution-verification

I had to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are both finite sets, then so is $A \cap B$ finite.  I solved it in a different way (using induction) and the grader said "that is not correct at all", I am really confused, I actually got help from this site with this question and it seemed correct!

This is how it went:

Let $A$ and $B$ both finite sets. If one of them is empty, $A \cap B$ is empty and thus finite.

Let $f$ be a one-to-one function and onto $A$ to: $\{1,2, \dots ,n\}$ and $g$ one-to-one and onto $B$ to $\{1,2, \dots, m\}$

I will prove that $A \cap B$ is finite using induction.

if $n=1$ then $A = \{f^{-1}(1)\}$ and thus $A \cap B = \emptyset$ OR $A \cap B = A$ and thus finite.

Assuming that $A \cap B$ is finite for $n=k$
We will try and prove this is correct for $n = k+1$

so:

$A \cap B = (\{f^{-1}(1), \dots , f^{-1}(k)\} \cap B) \cup (\{f^{-1}(k+1)\} \cap B)$

Because $\{f^{-1}(1) , \dots , f^{-1}(k)\} \cap B$ is finite (The assumption of the induction)  and we have $\{f^{-1}(k+1)\} \cap B$ which is finite (At most $1$ element)

So: $A \cap B$  is finite.

Where is the error in this solution? Is it not correct and thus the grader is right about saying "not correct"?
If it is correct, what should I tell him? how can I explain this more so that he will understand..
I am very confused.  Thank you very much!
Thank you!

Comment: It would be interesting to say what the grader said is wrong too.

Comment: @lebesgue I am not lying, he didnt ( which is frustrating so much!). Just wrote "not correct"

Comment: Nothing about lying. I assumed you had an one to one discussion. Just to see what he pointed out.

Comment: @lebesgue No no I said it as slang haha, ( like in a frustration) not that you thought I was lying ;)

Comment: Whether you argument is correct depends on several things that you’ve not told us. For instance, have you already proved that the union of two finite sets is finite? If not, your argument is incomplete.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It was a question that was broken to 3 pieces, first you had to prove that $A \cap B$ is finite, then $A \cup B$ is finite and then $ A \times B$ BUT - I think those 3 "sub-questions" are independent. If they are, does my argument hold? Thank you sir

Comment: I mean, let's say they are not independent and they do rely on each-other. I proved it 1 question after that so I think it should be OK right?

Comment: In your argument, $A \cap B = (\{f^{-1}(1), \dots , f^{-1}(k)\} \cap B) \cup (\{f^{-1}(k+1)\} \cap B)$ is true only if you have previously shown that finite union of finite sets are finite.

Comment: @lebesgue I proved that $A \cup B$ is finite as well if $A$ and $B$ are finite sets $1$ question after that, does that count?

Comment: Its hard to say for anyone. Since we dont know what was the definition of finite sets given and what results were proved previous to this (in your class may be). As such, if you would have proved that finite union of finite sets is finite using jus the definition of finite sets, it should be fine.

Comment: @StackOMeow: Your final step really does require that you already have the fact that the union of two finite sets is finite, or at least the result that adding one element to a finite set results in a finite set; if you’d given a proof that the union of two finite sets is finite that did not depend on the result for intersections **and referred to it in this proof**, you’d have been okay.

Comment: I will try and send a mail to the professor and ask if he could explain where he thinks the mistake is. I will write here what he answered. Thank you !

Comment: In fact, just one of $A$ and $B$ needs to be finite for $A \cap B$ to be finite, because any subset of a finite set is itself finite. The other could be infinite.